# Logarithmic track bar for zoom values of 1% to 1000%

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zooming, logarithm

I have a trackbar associated with a picture box where I am drawing an image based on the selected zoom factor. The range is from 1% to 1,000% so the lower you slide it, the faster it appears to zoom out.

This is expected but not desired. Is there a way to scale interpret the slider values so that zooming appears more natural to the user, specially in the < 50% range.

Comment: _"Is there a way to scale interpret the slider values"_ -- Of course. there is always "a way". What have _you_ tried? You may find it useful to consider using an `IValueConverter` in your binding. Or you may not. It's impossible to know, since you didn't provide any context here. A good question will include a good [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on ux.stackexchange, as you're really not asking for how to program something, but *what* you should program. That's a UX question. I'm skeptical that a slider is the right tool (at all)!

Comment: @ErikE: Thanks. I had not thought of that. The mathematical question still stands though. Out of curiosity.

Comment: But you haven't presented a mathematical question (or I would have answered it). You asked what looks natural or works "naturally" to human perception. If you describe a system of points that are anchored to certain zoom levels and are logarithmic between them, that I can answer. But for now, your question is, honestly, too vague to be about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

This is easily done:

```
myTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
myTrackBar.Maximim = 3000;

...

public double RealValue
{
    get
       {
          var trackPos = myTrackBar.Value;

          return Math.Pow(10.0, trackPos / 1000.0);
       }

  set 
       {
          var logValue = Math.Log10(value) * 1000;

          myTrackBar.Value = (int) logValue;
       }
}
```

To understand how this works, consider your range - 1 to 1000, or expressed as powers of 10 it is 1e0 to 1e3. Hence if we give the track bar a range from 0 to 3 and raise 10 to the value, we get a nice exponential set of values, just like you want.

But if we set the range to 0..3 we could only select from 4 different values: 0, 1, 2, 3 which would translate into 1, 10, 100 and 100 respectively.

To give us values inbetween, we simply multiply the range by a thousand, giving us 3001 different values that the track bar can keep track off, and then divide the trackbar's value by a thousand.